# Customize reports.html file inside jbehave\view folder

Tags: jbehave

I have to customize the reports.html file created inside jbehave\view folder. Is there any example available for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must check [this](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html) official reference.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to customize it by simply copying the `jbehave-reports.ftl` file from the JBehave jar into my test resources under the `ftl` directory. JBehave obviously reads the template from classpath at `ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl`, so the project-local file overrides the file from the jar.

Comment: i have added ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl in my project test resources, but its not working , do I need to anything else